# Evaluating an inequality

Tags: inequality

$\text{I want to find the domain of this inequality: } 2-\sqrt{x} \ge 0$

$\text{Besides } x \ge 0$,

Evaluating, raising to the second power first:

$$ -\sqrt{x} \ge -2 $$
$$ (-\sqrt{x})^2 \ge (-2)^2 $$
$$ x \ge 4 $$

Evaluating, multiplying it by $-1$ first:

$$ -\sqrt{x} \ge -2 $$
$$ (-1)\times(-\sqrt{x}) \ge (-1)\times(-2) $$
$$ \sqrt{x} \le -2 $$
$$ (\sqrt{x})^2 \le (2)^2 $$
$$ x \le 4 $$

Shouldn't we flip the inequality sign? Which one is correct and why?

Comment: Notice that $f(x)=x^2$ is decreasing on $]-\infty, 0]$

Comment: The second solution is correct. For the first one being wrong notice for example that $-1 \geq -2$ however $(-1)^2 = 1 \not \geq 4 = (-2)^2$